# Content Provider with a Real Time Framework [PubNub]

Tags: android, real-time, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver, pubnub

I am working on a personal side project that utilizes PubNub's real time framework.

My current understanding of Android's Content Provider is that it is used to help centralize an applications' content all in one place.

Therefore, when using a service, such as PubNub. Would a content provider be beneficial in a way that I may have missed?

I would like my app to update **individual/all row contents** (through the use of a Content Resolver) from listViews dynamically and have it update in real time on all connected devices as well. A quick google search tells me that I can update individual row contents without a Content Provider but would it have any additional use? Especially in conjunction with a real time framework?

Any help or thought would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** As a developing programmer, I decided to use a Content Provider in my application along with PubNub's real time framework. I do not regret my decision at all.

The Content Provider allows my application to keep a sorted table of the required values which I then use to publish onto PubNub's real time framework.

The Content Provider also allows me to perform functions on the table through the use of a cursor which I found to be extremely beneficial as well.

Answer (score 0):

Personal project with a pay service???  Think Crytical push messages are built into google play services.

Think Crytical.  Who has your data on a server how do you protect it.  Encrypt the data on your server first or risk exposing it then you'd have to have your app call your server to get the data.  It just doesn't work with a provider.  who becomes a point of disaster its not a good solution.  who knows all your clients its not a good solution.

**The best part is the custom content provider is your code so you can do whatever you like** when updates come in. For example maybe you delete a thumbnail when a delete comes in.

```
    File imgFile = new File(getContext().getExternalFilesDir(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), thumbnailname);
    if (imgFile.exists()) {
        imgFile.delete();
    }
```

Comment: PN is free for Indie Projects http://www.pubnub.com/free-evangelism-program/ and PN doesn't store your data unless you enable storage features.